# mongo db query and & or

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

Query :

```
[
Document{{$and=[
Document{{$in=Document{{ip=[127.0.0.1]}}}}, 
Document{{$in=Document{{dolaznaStr=[localhost:8080/mongoProjekat/treca, localhost:8080/mongoProjekat/cetvrta, localhost:8080/mongoProjekat/peta]}}}}
]}}, 
Document{{$group=Document{{_id=$dolaznaStr, count=Document{{$sum=1}}}}}}, 
Document{{$group=Document{{_id=$ip, count=Document{{$sum=1}}}}}}, 
Document{{$sort=Document{{count=-1}}}}, 
Document{{$limit=5}}
]
```

error: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 16436: 'exception: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$and'' on server 
Using mongo 3.X

Comment: add your original query and do format it properly so that it can be understood

Comment: Clearly not valid Java syntax. Please make an effort.

Comment: output =  collection.aggregate(pipeLineList);

pipeLineList : [
Document{{$and=[
Document{{$in=Document{{ip=[127.0.0.1]}}}}, 
Document{{$in=Document{{dolaznaStr=[localhost:8080/mongoProjekat/treca, localhost:8080/mongoProjekat/cetvrta, localhost:8080/mongoProjekat/peta]}}}}
]}}, 
Document{{$group=Document{{_id=$dolaznaStr, count=Document{{$sum=1}}}}}}, 
Document{{$group=Document{{_id=$ip, count=Document{{$sum=1}}}}}}, 
Document{{$sort=Document{{count=-1}}}}, 
Document{{$limit=5}}
]